# Lector de huellas en flutter

Tags: flutter

¿Como se podría hacer el proceso de lectura de huella digital y previa comparación con base de datos en servidor, utilizando flutter?

Comment: Muestra lo que has intentado

Comment: Te invito a que leas el articulo: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) aumentara tus posibilidades de recibir una respuesta.

Comment: Pudiste hacer algo?